# Linux guest VMs not using network settings in VMWare Workstation on Linux host and defaulting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, nat, vmware-workstation

I am trying to to have my linux guest vm use NAT or Custom settings but it is defaulting to 127.0.0.1. I was using it without issues yesterday but don't know what changed. I let the VMs and host PC on without changing settings.

Regardless of which Network setup I choose it is not taking my configuration and default to 127.0.0.1 if I run an ip a on the guest system.

[image]

My host system is running Fedora.

I think the issue it is trying to reference vmnet8 which is deleted (even when I run the program with elevated permissions). I don't know why it is referencing it.

[image]

These is the the config I have

[image]

[image]

The relevant parts of vmware.log

```
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0 APIC: version = 0x10, max LVT = 5, LDR = 0x0, DFR = 0xffffffff
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0 Active HV capabilities
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Full decode
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Nested paging A/D bits
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Guest physical width
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Real-address mode
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    TSC scaling
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Mode-based execute control for nested paging
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Virtualized VMSAVE/VMLOAD
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    CET Shadow Stacks
2023-10-06T23:46:23.475Z In(05) vcpu-0    Guest specific MSR_SPEC_CTRL
2023-10-06T23:46:23.476Z In(05) vcpu-0 TSC scaling ratio: 01_00000000 (mult=2147483648, shift=31)
2023-10-06T23:46:23.476Z In(05) vcpu-0 CPU reset: hard (mode Emulation)
2023-10-06T23:46:23.477Z In(05) vcpu-0 GuestRpc: Successfully created RPCI listening socket.
2023-10-06T23:46:23.477Z In(05) vcpu-0 GuestRpc: Using vsocket for TCLO messaging is disabled.
2023-10-06T23:46:23.477Z No(00) vcpu-0 ConfigDB: Unsetting all entries with prefix "usb_xhci:4."
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z In(05) vcpu-0 USB: Disconnecting device 0x2000000400000000
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z In(05) vcpu-0 USB: Connecting device desc:name:VMware\ Virtual\ USB\ Mouse vid:0e0f pid:0003 speed:full family:hid deviceType:virtual-hid info:0000005 version:5 id:0x200000050e0f0003
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z No(00) vcpu-0 ConfigDB: Setting usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z No(00) vcpu-0 ConfigDB: Setting usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z No(00) vcpu-0 ConfigDB: Setting usb_xhci:4.port = "4"
2023-10-06T23:46:23.484Z No(00) vcpu-0 ConfigDB: Setting usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 memoryHotplug: Node 0: Present: 1023 MB (100 %) Size:1023 MB (100 %)
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 PIIX4: PM Resuming from suspend type 0x0, chipset.onlineStandby 0
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 VNET: 'ethernet0' enable link state propagation, lsp.state = 5
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 VNET: MACVNetPortOpenDevice: Ethernet0: can't open vmnet device (No such file or directory)
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 VNET: MACVNetPort_Connect: Ethernet0: can't open data fd
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 Msg_Post: Warning
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 [msg.vnet.connectvnet] Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet8'. More information can be found in the vmware.log file.
2023-10-06T23:46:23.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 [msg.device.startdisconnected] Virtual device 'Ethernet0' will start disconnected.
```

Since I am on the latest version of Fedora and using the latest kernel headers I had to follow [this guide](http://rglinuxtech.com/?p=3174)  to install the vmmon and vmnet (which might be part of the issue).

I tried looking for the restore to default settings button in the Network Manager Editor but I think that is a Windows only feature since I don't have it. I also tried re-install VMWare with no success.

How do I reset my settings or get my NAT to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to to have my linux guest vm use NAT or Custom settings
> ..... I think the issue it is trying to reference vmnet8 which is
> deleted

I am in a VMware Workstation V17 VM here. (Kali Linux using NAT)

VMnet8 is the NAT interface inside VMware and should not be deleted.

VMNet 0 is normally used for Bridged Network. I suggest not using this but rather just use standard NAT.

Since you want to use NAT (reasonable to do) then you need to restore NAT in VMware Workstation.

You can try using the Network Editor; however, here it is probably much easier just to repair or reinstall VMware.

Make sure you have machine backups.

Try first try repairing VMware.  Close machines. Control Panel, Programs and Features, select VMware Workstation, change, and then repair.

See if that brings back NAT.

If not, uninstall VMware, restart and install it fresh. That will restore NAT.

Comment: I resolved it by recreating vmnet8 as a bridged connection and linking it to my NIC. Thank you!